# infinite solution system

Tags: linear-algebra

I just wanted to check if this was correct as my solutions keep being denied on the online system:

$$2x_1+x_2=-7$$
$$-6x_1-3x_2=21$$

I realize that both are essentially the same equation and hence I let $x=t$, and therefore the solution I arrive at is $(x,y)=(t, -7-2t).$ I cannot see why this answer is wrong, could anyone tell me where I went wrong as the online system does not seem to accept my answer.

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: How are you requested to insert the solution in the online form?

Comment: Your answer is correct. I guess the system did not detect that it is equivalent to the intented answer.

Comment: Your solution is perfectly correct. Perhaps the online system doesn't understand the parameter $t$?

Comment: I do not know how such systems work, but I think it only accepts a particular input. It is hard to guess how exactly the solution has to be entered in this case.

Comment: Maybe you could try writing the solutions as $x_{2}=-7-2x_{1}$, or to keep consistency $(x_{1},x_{2})=(t,-7-2t)$. Otherwise, I would say the system doesn't recognize the parameter $t$.

Comment: The online system is given as like a vector form with parameter $s$. 
$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}=$$\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
-7
\end{bmatrix}$$+s\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
-2
\end{bmatrix}$, this is what I wrote and still not correct so I suppose I will just email the professor.